# Existence of Fourier Series

Tags: hilbert-spaces, fourier-series

To prove the existence of a Fourier Series for a function obeying certain properties, is it sufficient to claim that if a function $\phi$ can be represented in Hilbert Space, it can also be represented as a Fourier Series, since the bases obey orthogonality when they are expressed as $e^{inx}$? 
$$\phi(x)=\sum^{\infty}\phi(x_n)\mid x_n \rangle=\sum^{\infty}a_{i}e^{inx}$$

Comment: at first you consider $\phi \in L^2([0,1]) = H$ and show : that $\{e^{2 i \pi n x}\}_{n \in \mathbb{Z}}$ is an orthonormal family of $H$, and that it spans the whole space (for example because the step functions are dense in $H$, and they have a fourier series (converging in the $L^2([0,1])$ sense)) i.e. $\{e^{2 i \pi n x}\}_{n \in \mathbb{Z}}$ is an orthonormal basis of $H$, so that $\phi \in H \implies \phi = \sum_n \langle \phi, e^{2 i \pi nx}\rangle e^{2 i \pi nx}$ (where again the convergence is in the $L^2([0,1])$ sense)

Comment: @user1952009 : Thanks, however, isn't $H=L^{2}(\mathbb{R})$?

Comment: no, the Fourier series are for periodic functions. if you consider $L^2(\mathbb{R})$ you'll need the Fourier transform